# How to use record with `class operator Initialize` as key or value of TDictionary?

Tags: delphi

I have the record `TFoo` with `class operator Initialize`:

```
  TFoo = record
    v: int32;
    class operator Initialize (out Dest: TFoo); // I omit empty implementation
  end;
```

When I trying to use TFoo as the key or the value of the `TDictionary`, for example:

```
  a: TDictionary<TFoo, Int32>; // or
  b: TDictionary<Int32, TFoo>;
```

then i get compilation error: `Can not open System.Generics.Collections.pas: no such file or directory`, and compiler inform me about internal error in console:

```
  [dcc32 Fatal Error] System.Generics.Collections.pas(7324): F2084 Internal Error: C31040
```

so, i look to 7324 line of the `System.Generics.Collections.pas`, and found, that the `Default()` function used for initialize `Entry` with default key and value of the record:

```
FItems[gap].Key := Default(K);
FItems[gap].Value := Default(V);
```

As far as I understand, `class operator Initialize` conflicts with the `Default()` dephi intrinsic. May be, this is a compiler bug. How to get around this problem?

Comment: This is a Delphi bug, please submit a bug report to Embarcadero

Comment: Reported - with minimal repro code: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41506